# NSLog the detected QR Code String

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app, I have a QR Code Scanner. How do I NSLog the string from the QR Code?

Do I type:

```
NSLog(@"%@", AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode);
```

?

Please help, this is very important

Comment: Look at the `stringValue` property of `AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject` [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject/stringValue)

Answer (score 2):

```
[objMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject stringValue]
```

use this line for `NSLog` for the above value. Something like

```
NSLog(@"%@",[objMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject stringValue]);
```